# Calling app from subprocess.call with arguments

Tags: python, process, python-2.6, raspberry-pi

I'm a beginner in Python, and I've been trying to call a command line app, but it fails:

```
>>> import subprocess as s
>>> s.call("gpio -g read 17")
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 470, in call
        return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 623, in __init__
        errread, errwrite)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1141, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

But then if I add `shell=True` it all starts working. Can someone explain why?

```
>>> import subprocess as s
>>> s.call("gpio -g read 17", shell=True)
>>> 0
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You're not using call right. Look at [the introduction](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) or any of the examples in the docs. The first argument of call is "args", a sequence of arguments, where arg[0] is the program to run.

So, when you do this:

```
s.call("gpio -g read 17")
```

There are two ways subprocess could interpret this. It should run a program called "g" with arguments "p", "i", "o", " ", etc. (Remember, strings are sequences of characters.) It might instead run a program called "gpio -g read 17" with no additional arguments. Either way, it's not going to find such a program. (Unless you happen to have a program called "g" or "gpio -g read 17" on your PATH, in which case it'll do the wrong thing instead of giving you an error…)

What you want is:

```
s.call(["gpio", "-g", "read", "17"])
```

So, why does this work if you pass `shell=True`? Because this whole string gets passed to the shell, which then does its own parsing of the command line and separates things by spaces. It's like calling `os.system("gpio -g read 17")`.

Please note that all of the above is a bit oversimplified (it ignores Windows, and shell parsing isn't really just "separate by spaces", and so on), so you should actually read the documentation. (Also, whoever wrote the `subprocess` docs is a better writer than me.)

Comment: And with `shell = True`, this command is sent to a shell, which then does the splitting argument splitting.

Comment: @MarkIngram -- apparently we were commenting at the same time.

Comment: Actually, I saw the question and started editing my answer, and then when I clicked "Save" your answer appeared…