# How to pass commands to an application from python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, command, subprocess

I am trying to run ffmpeg application from python.I am using the following code to execute the application

> import subprocess
>   subprocess.call(['C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe'])

by this command the application is getting executed. could somebody tell me how can i pass commands to the application, i tried

> subprocess.call(['C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe','ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 -vn -ab 128 outputaudio.mp3'])

but its not working.

Comment: you don't want to pass commands to your application but arguments. Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801098/calling-app-from-subprocess-call-with-arguments

Answer (score 2):

They need to be individual args:

```
subprocess.check_call(['C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe','ffmpeg','-i',"2.mp4","-vn", "-ab", "128", "outputaudio.mp3"])
```

Also use `check_call` instead of `call`, `check_call` will raise a CalledProcessError if the command returns a non-zero exit status.
I am not sure the `'ffmpeg'` should be there.

Comment: sir, you are right, when i used "check_call" method, I am getting "CalledProcessError " even for running ffmpeg.exe file .could you please tell me how i can run the application and pass argumrnts.

Comment: does `C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe` exist?

Answer (score 1):

The arguments should each be separate elements in the list. The [doc page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) has an example of how to call it. Yours should be something like this:

```
['C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe','ffmpeg','-i 2.mp4','-vn','-ab','128','outputaudio.mp3']
```