# Using subprocess.call with an argument

Tags: python, command-line, environment-variables, sublimetext3

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801098/calling-app-from-subprocess-call-with-arguments)

The question in principle is the same, I have a subprocess.system call

```
...
EDITOR = os.environ.get('EDITOR', 'vim')
subprocess.call([EDITOR, tf.name])
...
```

Where `EDITOR` is the environments `$EDITOR` variable, `tf.name` is just a filename.

However, [sublime text](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html) suggest to set the `$EDITOR` to `export EDITOR='subl -w'` Making my call look like this:

```
subprocess.call(['subl -w', "somefilename"])
```

And it fails like this:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/note", line 65, in <module>
    storage["notes"][args.name] = writeNote(args.name, storage)
  File "/usr/bin/note", line 54, in writeNote
    subprocess.call([EDITOR, tf.name])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 557, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1541, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'subl -w'
```

Of course, it's supposed to look likie this

```
subprocess.call([subl", "-w" "somefilename"])
```

A workaround would perhaps be

```
args = EDITOR.split(" ")
subprocess.call(args + ["somefilename"])
```

But I'm a little wary of doing this, because I cannot know what `$EDITOR` is set to, is this safe to do?

What's the proper way to handle this case?

Comment: @andlrc No not a duplicate, that's not my question. I know how to access environment variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rather use shlex. It takes care of UNIX shell like commands.
For example:
`>>> shlex.split( "folder\ editor" ) + ["somefilename"]`
`['folder editor', 'somefilename']`
`>>> shlex.split( "editor -arg" ) + ["somefilename"]`
`['editor', '-arg', 'somefilename']`

So you should be able to directly do:
`subprocess.call( shlex.split(EDITOR) + ["somefilename"] )`